# MYSQL and IN in requests

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner when it comes to using mysql queries embedded inside other mysql queries using the IN statement.

I currently have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT BorName
FROM Borrower
WHERE BorId IN (
    SELECT Borrower.BorId
    FROM Loan
    WHERE Loan.BcId IN (
        SELECT BookCopy.BcId
        FROM BookCopy
        WHERE BookCopy.BtId In (
            SELECT BookTitle.BtId
            FROM BookTitle
            WHERE BookTitle.PubId In (
                SELECT Publisher.PubId
                FROM Publisher
                WHERE  `PubName` = CONVERT( _utf8 'Methuen' USING latin1 ) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

I am basically trying to find out if a borrower has borrowed a book from the publisher Methuen. I just cant seem to work out what is wrong, I have gone through each individual statement and they all seem to work just not the overall request with all of the IN statements.

Can anyone spot what is wrong?

Comment: Will this work using inner joins?

Comment: Join all of the tables together before getting the data I want?

Comment: If the join doesn't return any results the user has not borrowed the book.  No need for subqueries.

Comment: Yes. I think you could use inner joins to get the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like suggested, JOINs are a much cleaner, and likely a more efficient way to do this query as opposed to nested INs:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.BorName
FROM 
    Borrower b
    JOIN Loan l ON l.BorId = b.BorId
    JOIN BookCopy bc ON bc.BcId = l.BcId
    JOIN BookTitle bt ON bt.BtId = bc.BtId
    JOIN Publisher p ON p.PubId = bt.PubID
WHERE
    p.PubName = CONVERT( _utf8 'Methuen' USING latin1 ) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci
```

Additionally, I think there was a problem in your first sub-query:

```
SELECT Borrower.BorId
FROM Loan
WHERE Loan.BcId IN...
```

I believe should have been:

```
SELECT Loan.BorId
FROM Loan
WHERE Loan.BcId IN...
```

Comment: Perfect, Helped me streamline my query as well as spotting my error!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Replace all the `IN` by `=`

Obviously using joins will be much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if MySQL supports the with clause but in SQL Server you are able to use something called a Common Table Expression.  This is a ANSII SQL spec that should be easily determined.

Psuedo:

```
With
    someMadeUpTableAlias AS
    (
        SELECT...
    )
SELECT ...
FROM 
    OutsideTable AS A
    someMadeUpTableAlias AS B ON (A. = B.)
```

I have been making a large effort to take advantage of the CTE's because of the readability inherently not there with subqueries.  You may want to take a look at the side effects as behind the scenes it would be creating a temporary table and mysql may have some performance hits associated.  Easiest way to tell is clear your query cache and run it both ways.